# Easy way to double bind length of angular array where object has 'true' for a specific property?

Tags: angular, angular-arrays

I have the following list of students:

```
students = [{name:'Jordan', passed:true}, {name:'Kyle'},{name:'Jess'},
            {name:'Sam', passed:true}
           ]
```

I want to be able to, in an HTML template, get the length of the array where the student passed.

Normally I would do:

```
<div>
    {{students.length}}
</div>
```

However, I want something like this pseudocode...

```
<div>
    {{total length of students who passed}}
</div>
```

I want to make it so that if I have other buttons on the page that modify students so that when I change whether a student passes or not, the template will automatically reflect the correct number of students.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in angular template, try to use a `Pipe` or `invoking a method` from your Component's class instead of doing it inside the template. I am suggesting to you `Pipes`.

In the template:

```
<div>
    {{ queryArray() }}
</div>
```

In the component:

```
queryArray() {
   return this.students.filter(c => c.passed).length;
}
```

For Pipe

In the html:

```
<div>{{students | myLengthFilter:'passed' }}</div>
```

In the pipe class:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myLengthFilter'
})
export class MyLengthFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], field: string): any {
    if (!items || !field) {
      return items;
    }
    // filter items array, items which match and return true will be
    // kept, false will be filtered out
    return items.filter(c => c[field]).length;
  }
}
```

Comment: *Pure* pipe is definitely more preferable here due to its efficiency (given that `students` is immutable).

Comment: Is it possible to pass a parameter to MyLengthFilterPipe (say the name of the key? (passed in this case)

Comment: @Rolando, yes brother.